# Getting SSL error in dotnet command line

Tags: .net, ssl, openssl, .net-core

I got this issu since this morning.
I was not able anymore to restore/build/add package from dotnet command line.

I got the following error :

```
» dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 pour .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

  Restauration des packages pour /home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Impossible de charger l'index de service pour la source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]

ÉCHEC de la build.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Impossible de charger l'index de service pour la source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file [/home/ebernard/Documents/python/test_dotnet_console/retard-cli/retard-cli.csproj]
    0 Avertissement(s)
    1 Erreur(s)

Temps écoulé 00:00:01.53
```

It clearly an issue with ssl but I was not able to fix it.
I try to reinstall dotnet-sdk, openssl, it change nothing.

Have you an idea where this can come from ?

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Edit 2: I try `dotnet build` from inside a Docker and it works so I think the issu come from my installation.

Comment: On what OS? Use Wireshark to analyze TLS handshakes first, as that would reveal initial data to get you started.

Comment: @LexLi I'm on ubuntu. I try to dotnet command inside a docker and it work with the same version. So it seem I have break something/wrong certificate on my computer but I don't know where. The error don't precise which file missing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it come from a missing certificate.

In my `/etc/ssl/certs`, I have a dead link to a missing certificate (`0c31d5ce -> ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem`).

I recreate the missing certificate with the following command and everything work again.

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```